# Riemann sum approximation answer

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

Use the Riemann sum with $n=2$ rectangles to approximate $ \int_{0}^{1} \frac1{x^4+1} \,dx $. Round to $3$ decimal places. Options are

1. 0.867
2. 0.721
3. 0.971
4. 1.441

When I take right Riemann rectangle then the answer is 0.721 and when I take left rectangle then the answer is 0.971. When I take middle point then the answer is 0.878. So what is the answer of this question? Please help.

Comment: That is indeed strange. Are you sure you copied the problem statement exactly?

Comment: Using the midpoint is generally not what is meant by "Riemann sums". But the matter of whether it is option 2 or option 3 is just an error on the part of either the author of the question or you as the transcriber of the question.